# Riesz' Representation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Riesz' Representation Theorem given by Walter Rudin in his book Real and Complex Analysis and I have doubts.

The first doubt is something about set theory. In STEP VI, there are sets $A,B\in\mathfrak{M}_F$, compacts sets $K_1$ and $K_2$, and open sets $V_1$ and $V_2$ such that $K_1\subset A\subset V_1$ and $K_2\subset B\subset V_2$. The thing is that he says that it is true:

$$A\setminus B\subset V_1\setminus K_2\subset(V_1\setminus K_1)\cup(K_1\setminus V_2)\cup(V_2\setminus K_2)$$

and I don't know what's reason.

On the other hand, at the end of the proof, I cannot see why the equality marked by a red dot is true:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first question take  a point on the left side and show that it belongs to the right side. For the second question just note that every term on the left side is there on the right side and vice-versa. Both are very elmentary.

Comment: There's no $2\cdot\varepsilon\cdot\mu(K)$ anywhere, or at least, I cannot see it.

Comment: I recommend that don't use Rudin's book to study, just to consult. They are not useful as textbooks. I can't understand why people use them or why they are so popular, they are terrible.

Comment: You've left some crucial context out of your question.  For the equation with the red dot you just need to use the fact that $\ E_i\ $ are disjoint sets whose union is $\ K\ $, from which it follows that $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^n\mu\big(E_i\big)=\mu(K)\ $.  The identity falls out if you replace $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^n(|a|+y_i+\epsilon)\mu\big(E_i\big)\ $on the left side of the equation with $\ (|a|+\epsilon)\mu(K)+\sum_\limits{i=1}^n y_i\mu\big(E_i\big)\ $, and $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^n(y_i-
\epsilon)\mu\big(E_i\big)\ $ on the right with $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^n y_i\mu\big(E_i\big)-\epsilon\mu(K)\ $.

Comment: Thank you very much, @lonzaleggiera